# ответ бота на запрос один раз в n-ое количество времени

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Есть бот телеграм на PHP, нужно сделать так чтобы при определённом запросе, ответ пользователю можно было получить всего 1 раз в допустим 20 секунд.

Были попытки сделать это через сессию, но все было не удачно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Новым подходом к достижению этой функциональности было бы использование базы данных для хранения последнего времени, когда пользователь отправлял запрос, и полученного ответа. Вот пример реализации:

```
    <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');

// Проверьте, делал ли пользователь запрос за последние 20 секунд
function checkRequestTime($chatId) {
    global $mysqli;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE chat_id=$chatId";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $last_request_time = strtotime($row['request_time']);
        $time_diff = time() - $last_request_time;
        if ($time_diff < 20) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Сохраняйте время запроса и ответ
function storeRequest($chatId, $message) {
    global $mysqli;
    $query = "REPLACE INTO requests (chat_id, request_time, response) VALUES ($chatId, NOW(), '$message')";
    $mysqli->query($query);
}

// Проверьте, может ли пользователь сделать запрос и отправить ответ
function sendResponse($chatId, $message) {
    if (checkRequestTime($chatId)) {
        // Отправьте ответ
        // ...
        
        // Сохраняйте время запроса и ответ
        storeRequest($chatId, $message);
    } else {
        // Отправьте сообщение, указывающее, что пользователю необходимо подождать
        // ...
    }
}
?>
```